# F# Console.ReadLine not waiting for input

Tags: recursion, io, f#

I'm new to F#, apologies if I'm missing something obvious here.
I have the following code, with the intent to get user input and convert it to a uint:

```
let println ln =
    printfn "%s" ln

let rec getUserKeyInput =
    let x = System.Console.ReadKey()
    string x

let getInputWithPrompt prompt =
    println prompt
    getUserKeyInput

let rec getUserUIntFromStr str =
    try
        let i = str |> uint
        i
    with
        | :? System.FormatException -> println "Please enter a positive integer";
                                       (getUserUIntFromStr (getUserKeyInput))
```

When getUserUIntFromStr is called with `let i = getUserUIntFromStr str` "Please enter a positive integer" is printed infinitely. I've also tried Console.ReadLine() and stdin.ReadLine(), both in interactive and from main, with the same results. It looks to me like none of the "Read" functions are waiting for input, but that doesn't seem right and I'm guessing I've done something wrong. Any suggestions?

Comment: `getUserKeyInput` is a value, not a function. It's evaluated only once at init time, not every time you reference it.

Comment: Ah, I see, thank you. . Please add this as an answer

Comment: ```let getUserKeyInput () =
    let x = System.Console.ReadKey()
    string x``` is now a function, and you call it in ```let getInputWithPrompt prompt =
    println prompt
    getUserKeyInput ()``` supplying a unit argument, then it runs every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getUserKeyInput` is a value, not a function. It's evaluated only once at init time, not every time you reference it.

To make it a function, you need to give it a parameter. What type of parameter? Well, technically any type will do, but F# has you covered: for situations where you need to have some value, but there isn't a sensible value to use (which happens surprisingly often), there is a special type `unit` with a single value denoted as parentheses `()`:

```
let getUserKeyInput () =
    let x = System.Console.ReadKey()
    string x
```

(also note that `rec` is unnecessary, because the function isn't actually recursive)
(also note that `ReadKey` takes such parameter as well - it's the same deal there)

And then pass the parameter to call the function:

```
  println "Please enter a positive integer"
  getUserUIntFromStr (getUserKeyInput ())
```